# How to open internal storage from a iPhone using Windows 10

Tags: file-management

When I tried to open internal storage on my Windows HP it routes me to a DCIM file which is empty how can I open the internal storage of the iPhone or iPod also powershell is disabled and will not allow me to use once I click on iPhone icon

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your phone.  Windows should ask you what you want to do (notification). Choose the bottom (IIRC) option and Explorer will show the phone. Double click on the icon and drill down until the DCIM folder opens.

Your files (if they exist) should be there. I double checked this on my own phone.

If there are no files, you may have deleted them.